# Case insensitive filter query with Objectify + google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, case-insensitive, objectify

Is there an easy way to do a case insensitive filter query with Objectify + google appengine (Java)? Essentially this is what I am trying to do except that I need the filter on email to be  case insensitive.

```
Objectify objectifyService = ObjectifyService.begin();
objectifyService.query(AppUser.class).filter("email", email).get();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store your email address in a normalized (lowercase or uppercase, for instance) form in the datastore, and query on that. If you also need the original unmodified email address, you should store both separately.

Comment: Thanks -- it is normalized now but we have an issue with existing email addresses that were grandfathered in. I also posted on the objectify-appengine google group and one of the responders essentially gave the same response as you did and  added a GAE request to store the case-sensitive version of a string property, but index/filter by the case-insensitive version.

Answer (score 0):

In case of queries we convert everything to a similar case and then do the comparison.

```
select * from account where upper(email) = upper('test@gmail.com');
```

In your case you could try.

```
objectifyService.query(AppUser.class).filter("upper(email)", email.toUpperCase()).get();
```

I am not sure if this will work with Objectify, you could give it a try.

Comment: You can't do this in App Engine - and it'll be O(n) on any other database, too.