# Objectify - Case in sensitive - GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, case-insensitive

How an we get data or filter the list without case sensitive?

Example: I have list of records in GAE DB like: {Test, test}

I want to get both of them(Test and test) when I enter 't' OR 'T' in search filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive filter query with Objectify + google appengine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201082/case-insensitive-filter-query-with-objectify-google-appengine)

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Is there any simple solution than that?

Comment: Nope. Store data in a searchable format if you want to search for it. E.g. twice, once in regular case e.g. `Töst`, once in normalized form e.g. `toest`, then search on one property and display the other.

Answer (score 1):

Using objectify, you will need to normalise and store a duplicate property.

For a more flexible solution, consider storing a document in [the search api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/). This will give you normalisation, stemming and advanced ordering and scoring at the cost of needing to coordinate writes and searches across the search index and the datastore.